# Open php file in browser using http://localhost with applescript

Tags: macos, applescript, mamp, textwrangler

I'm trying to write an Applescript for textwrangler that will open the active document in Chrome. This is what the script looks like at the moment:

```
tell application "TextWrangler" to set theFile to file of document 1
tell application "Finder" to open theFile using (path to application "Google Chrome")
```

Let's say I an working on a file with the absolute path 'Applications/MAMP/www/index.php'. The script will open that file in the browser as 'file:// localhost/Applications/MAMP/www/index.php', showing the php code.

Instead of this I need a script that will replace 'file:// localhost/Applications/MAMP/' with 'http:// localhost/' showing the actual site.

I have tried a bunch of stuff that I found online, but I have too little experience with Applescript to achieve this.

Comment: I have spaces before localhost in order to submit this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this, following Chase's lead and using javascript to do the string replacing.

```
property delim : "MAMP" -- where to break the path and prepend localhost to

tell application "TextWrangler" to set theFile to file of document 1

tell application "Finder" to set p to the POSIX path of theFile -- convert it into a Unix path first

tell application "Google Chrome" to execute front window's active tab javascript ("pth='" & p & "';window.open('http://localhost'+ pth.split('" & delim & "').pop());")
```

Makes for hard to read code with the multi language concatenation and string delimiting, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just open that url, you would use something like this:

```
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    do JavaScript "window.open('http:// localhost/')" in document 1
end tell
```

hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, but what I am looking for is to basically trim the original path (string?) and then add the 'http://localhost/' bit to the beginning of it.

Comment: Can you just add a variable with the string in it and use && to put it in the tell?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple different options..

The first assumes that the file you want to open is at the root localhost directory.  The script will instruct Safari to open the [localhost](/questions/tagged/localhost) URL and append the filename to the path.

*The first time you run this [applescript](/questions/tagged/applescript) you may be required to authorize Mac Accessibility allowing Finder to complete the necessary actions.*

```aea
try
    tell application "Finder" to set filePath to name of item 1 of (get selection)
        set the clipboard to filePath

        set localhost to "http://localhost/"

        tell application "Safari"
            activate
            tell application "System Events"
                tell process "Safari"
                    click menu item "New Tab" of menu "File" of menu bar 1

                end tell
            end tell
            set theURL to localhost & filePath
            set URL of document 1 to theURL
        end tell
    end tell
end try
```

---

Another option would be to copy the POSIX path of the selected file and open the local path in Safari..

```aea
try
    set filePath to {}
    tell application "Finder"
        repeat with objItem in (get selection)
            set end of filePath to POSIX path of (objItem as text)
        end repeat
    end tell

    set {strDelimeter, text item delimiters} to {text item delimiters, return}
    set the clipboard to filePath as text

    tell application "Safari" to open location filePath

end try
```